# Is there another way to removed the whitespace inside the Command.Text?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

This is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Stud_ID, LCase(Stud_Fname)&LCase(Stud_Lname) AS name FROM tbl_Student";
            OleDbDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader1.Read()){
                Console.WriteLine(reader1[1].ToString());
            }
            reader1.Close();
```

The expected out put that I want to achieve was [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ecF.png) the Stud_Fname and Lname will combine and it will be as lowerCase. but my problem was I need to removed the whitespace between the name with 2 given name such as Dela Cruz. It should be delacruz . What I tried is the .Replace(); and .Trim() but it didn't work can someone help me. suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` should work:

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Stud_ID, LCase(Replace(Stud_Fname, ' ', '') & LCase(Stud_Lname) AS name FROM tbl_Student";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessTest))
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT ID, Firstname, LastName, Active," +
            "Replace(lcase([Firstname]) & lcase([LastName]),' ','') as FullName FROM tblPeople";

        using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        }
    }
}
```

So, we remove all spaces - in first or last name.